# When does time supply capped count?

Tags: starcraft-2

After playing a match you get a lot of statistics, one of them being Time Supply Capped.

[image: Time Supply Capped]

This sums up how long time you have been at your supply cap, but does it also count if you are at max supply cap? (200/200)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is great explanation from **[RhokenStrolm](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/1648785/1/RhokenStrolm/)**

> "Supply Capped" is where you are **trying to build a unit but can't
>   because you don't have enough supply**.

And about 200/200...

> **It doesn't measure 200/200**. It measures when you are supply blocked
>   and stops when you build a pylon/depot/overlord.

[Source.](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/8087089152)

Answer (score 4):

It **doesn't measure** if you are at 200/200.

The goal of the statistic is so you can see how many seconds you wasted not being able to produce units due to lack of supply depots,and since supply depots can't increase your capacity over 200 the timer stops telling you it isn't your fault anymore.

Interesting question would be if it counts when you are at 49/50 since it isn't maxed but you can't make any useful unit...As far as i know it doesn't count that either.